# Using one-to-many relationship throws Primary Key Exception on inner object

Tags: entity-framework

Any idea why Entity Framework is trying to save an inner object that already exists in the database?

```
public partial class ConatainerClass : EntityPbject
{
    public InnerClass InnerClass {get; set;}

}

ObjectContext.ContainerClass.AddObject(newContainerClassObject);
ObjectContext.SaveChanges;
```

Creating a new ContainerClass, attaching an existing InnerClass, and calling Context.SaveChanges() generates a PK_Constraint error on the InnerClass.

Comment: OK, its an EntityObject - they're both EntityObjects. This is pseudo code. The classes are generated by the entity data modeler. I'm used to working with POCO. This behavior of trying to save an object that has not changed is a little beyond me.

Comment: This is code I am maintaining. The problem was the inner class was created through code and not part of the Context being used to update the outer class. The inner class and the inner class foreign key were being assigned to the outer class. I removed the inner class assignment and the outer class saves fine with only the foreign key reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code I am maintaining. The problem was the inner class was created through code and not part of the Context being used to update the outer class. The inner class and the inner class foreign key were being assigned to the outer class. I removed the inner class assignment and the outer class saves fine with only the foreign key reference.